# Ler multiplas variaveis na mesma linha (Scala)

Tags: variáveis, input, scala

Necessito ler três variáveis na mesma linha em Scala, li uma resposta em inglês mas o método não funcionou, "readLine" e "toInt" não são reconhecidos. Segue meu código. Se alguém souber uma forma que funcione agradeço.

```scala
object main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val Array(cd1,nr1,vr1) = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
    val Array(cd2,nr2,vr2) = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
    val total : Double = nr1*vr1 + nr2+vr2
    println(f"VALOR A PAGAR = $total%.2f")
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu resolvi aqui galera, mas se alguém tiver uma solução menos verbosa e/ou mais sofisticada e que não necessite chamar uma bibioteca eu ficaria grato em conhecer. Segue o código:

```scala
import java.util.Scanner
import java.util.Locale

object main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US)
    /* Criei um objeto scanner, setando como entrada dele o teclado (StdIn) 
separando os frames por espaço (" ") */
    val scan  = new Scanner(scala.io.StdIn.readLine()).useDelimiter(" ")
    val cd1 : Int = scan.nextInt()
    val nr1 : Int = scan.nextInt()
    val vr1 : Double = scan.nextDouble()
    val scan2  = new Scanner(scala.io.StdIn.readLine()).useDelimiter(" ")
    /* Como eu faço leitura de dois inputs contendo 3 dados cada eu criei um segundo
scanner para ler os dados do segundo input. */
    val cd2 : Int = scan2.nextInt()
    val nr2 : Int = scan2.nextInt()
    val vr2 : Double = scan2.nextDouble()
    val total : Double = nr1*vr1 + nr2*vr2
    println(f"VALOR A PAGAR: R$$ $total%.2f")
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int A = entrada.nextInt();
        int B = entrada.nextInt();
        double C = entrada.nextDouble();
        int D = entrada.nextInt();
        int E = entrada.nextInt();
        double F = entrada.nextDouble();
        double resultado = (B*C)+(E*F);
        System.out.printf("VALOR A PAGAR: R$ %.2f\n",resultado);
```

Enviei assim e passou.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).